# SQL Returning number of rows in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I've got a SQL query that returns the total number of rows in a table. The number of rows on this particular table is 25 - that is the value i want to return

```
$nOfReviews=$db->query("SELECT count(*) as total from review WHERE film_id = $film_id ");
```

If i do

```
$count = $nOfReviews->fetch_assoc();
print_r($count);
```

it returns

```
Array ( [total] => 25 )
```

Fantastic! i'm on the right the track. It knows which filmId to look for, it is counting the number of rows correctly. I just need a way for it to output '25'.

Any ideas?

Comment: echo $count['total'];

Answer (score 2):

You can do as following:
`echo $count['total']`;

Answer (score 0):

The array is `$count`, the key is `total`, the value is `25`.

Try

```
echo $count["total"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an array and can be accesed by using subscript operator i.e []. Objects need to be accessed by an arrow so you know the difference between them. Just do echo `$count['total']` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you print it

```
  echo $count['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Also,

```
$count = $nOfReviews->mysqli_num_rows();
```

Instead Of

```
$count = $nOfReviews->fetch_assoc();
```

Ehich Return Simply the number only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$nOfReviews=$db->query("SELECT count(*) as total from review WHERE film_id = $film_id ");
$count = $nOfReviews->num_rows();
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to get total number of rows

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0];
```